# Как много времени тратит функция srand(time(NULL))?

Tags: c++, время, случайные-числа

Сильно ли использование `srand(time(NULL))` замедляет код, если эта функция выполняется в цикле наряду с остальным кодом? (примерно 10000 итераций в секунду, комп обычный)
Функция `rand()` будет использоваться ~500 000 000 раз

Comment: Она там выполняться не должна и совсем не из-за скорости.

Comment: практически у всех домашних заданиях и детских поделках, эта функция должна вызываться строго один или ноль раз в самом начале.

Comment: там поиск хорошего решения с помощью произвольной выборки из 2^550 вариантов, я не уверен что одного вызова srand() будет достаточно

Comment: Множественное использование `srand(time(NULL))` - прекрасный способ сделать функцию `rand()` еще хуже чем она уже есть.

Comment: Лучше не использовать rand(), а использовать функции библиотеки [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Главное - если в цикле, который выполняется 1000 итераций в секунду, выполнять `srand`, вы будете получать по 1000 **одинаковых** "случайных" чисел.

`rand()` вычисляет очередное случайное число на основании предыдущего значения, ну, а `srand` это предыдущее значение устанавливает. Поскольку обычно `time(NULL)` возвращает значение времени в секундах, получается, что в пределах одной секунды все ваши `rand()` будут одинаковы. Да и в разные секунды получаемые числа могут быть не случайны - все же они получаются из последовательных значений.

`srand(time(NULL))` должен вызываться один-единственный раз.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы оптимизировать код, эту функцию стоит вызвать 1 раз перед циклом, все равно при каждом запуске программы рандомизация будет разной. Кстати желательно использовать вместо NULL nullptr . Ну и соответсвтенно оптимизация будет равна = (кол-во итераций)*(кол-во тиков для выполнения функции). Сколько тиков стоит эта функция я не знаю, однако т.к. она в цикле постоянно вызывается, должна стоить в сумме дорого.

Comment: То есть srand() использовать только 1 раз даже если в цикле планируется 550 000 000 вызовов функции rand()?

Comment: Функция srand() используется для установки начала последовательности, генерируемой функ­цией rand(). Да, если у вас так много итерацией, вы хорошо сэкономите время, вызвав ее до цикла

Comment: Еще лучше [сделать ассемблерную вставку](http://www.manhunter.ru/assembler/5_generator_sluchaynih_chisel_na_assemblere.html), для получения случайных чисел, но т.к. с++ достаточно быстрый, значительного прироста не будет, однако все же так будет быстрее.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это в самом деле *хороший* генератор? Вообще, ГПСЧ вещь весьма капризная, почитайте хотя бы у Кнута